# Drupal-7: Feed Import custom cron jobs from the same module

Tags: import, drupal-7, cron, feed, cron-task

I have Drupal 7 installation with Feed Import module enabled (not the same as Feeds module!). From this module I need to import data from several xml feeds with a different schedule. For example feed A should be imported once a day, but feed B - once a week.

I have done research and suggestions are that Elysia Cron or Ultimate Cron should help to do this. However I can't figure out what needs to be done to actually achieve that different feeds can be imported on different times.

If I take Ultimate Cron case as an example, then using their API ultimate_cron.api.php https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron I have found following suggestion:

I create a hook in Feed Import module, and define a new cron task (to import feed which is already defined in Feed Import by name "test API feed RAW"). Code looks like this:

```
function feed_import_base_cronapi() {
  $items = array();

  $items['test_api_feed_raw_cron'] = array(
    'title' => t('test API feed RAW')
  );

  return $items;
}
```

However when I go to Cron page in administrative layout and manually execute newly created task, nothing happens. It shows that cron task has been executed successfully, but no data is imported.

It seems that this newly created task is not actually linked with the feed that is defined in Feed Import module. Or that it is not triggering import of that feed.

What am I missing and doing wrong here? I'm not so strong with php and module development, any help will be appreciated.

I have already googled and looked for various solutions, but nothing works. I really feels like I'm missing something very basic and obvious. But of course it could be also opposite and I'm trying to achieve something really complicated..

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution with a help from a colleague. Will post it here if someone would have need for it some day.

I'm missing a callback function here that triggers the actual feed import. And also I changed from Ultimate Cron to Elysia cron. (not sure if that actually makes a difference here though)

the actual function that triggers feed import is from feed_import_base.module

```
_feed_import_base_process_feed($feed);
```